# gdb cannot insert breakpoint in child processes

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, fork

First of all, I have seen a couple similar questions here but they didn't quite solve my problem, so I'll give it a try here.

I'm using gdb on *"a very simple HTTP server for Unix, using fork()"* based on [here](https://gist.github.com/laobubu/d6d0e9beb934b60b2e552c2d03e1409e).

Βasically a new child gets forked each time there is a new connection. And I want to insert a breakpoint on a function `func_name` that is called by every child that handles a request.

If I have understood correctly, I must first use

`set follow-fork-mode child`

and then

`set detatch-on-fork off` (??? not sure about that)

And after these two commands, I type

`break func_name`

and then `run`, but when I create a connection and it's time for the child to call `func_name`, gdb says

`Warning: Cannot insert breakpoint 1. Cannot access memory at address 0x1632`

So what is going on here? What am I missing?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Typo? You want `set detach-on-fork child` since you want to break on the _child_ function. But, address `0x1632` looks suspicious (i.e. out-of-range). Usually, the code addresses are in a higher range. You should really _edit_ your post and post your _entire_ code in a code block.

Comment: @CraigEstey Not a typo, no. According to [here](https://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/set_detach-on-fork) `set detach-on-fork` can only take `on` or `off` values.

Comment: The typo was referring to `detatch` [vs. `detach`]. Oops, my bad. You want `off` [with fork mode `child`]. I use `gdb` with a wrapper script and I was looking at the wrong line. But, your issue is probably related to the address. What does `p func_name` show?

Comment: The function is actually called `route` and, before running the program, `p route` shows `$1 = {void ()} 0x1197 <route>` and while running it shows  `Cannot access memory at address 0x1197`. If you want to have a look at the actual code, it is [here](https://github.com/chatziko/pico/blob/master/main.c).

Comment: I can confirm this bug on Debian 10, gdb 7.12, with a PIE executable. But things work fine with a `-fno-pie` executable. And gdb 9.2 works OK with a PIE executable. Test program is `#include <unistd.h> #include <sys/types.h> #include <sys/wait.h> int route() { return sleep(10); } int main(int argc, char **argv) { pid_t p; p = fork(); if (p == 0) route(); else wait(NULL); }`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you, it was a PIE executable, now I changed it and it works fine. One more thing. The first time a child is forked, gdb switches to the child, but when the child finishes gdb does not switch back to the parent process (which is ideally what I would want to happen). For example, if I type `continue` it says `The program is not being run`. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: @DaMike I don't know of a way to do what you ask, but it might be a nice feature to add to gdb. (Right now, you can use the `inferior` command to continue the parent.) Can you ask it as a separate, new question?

Comment: I did some crude bisection (at the release level), and it looks like gdb gets that **Cannot insert breakpoint** error up through version 8.1.1 and it works correctly in gdb 8.2.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I actually managed to do the switching I wanted between parent and child with the `inferior` command! Help appreciated!